# Is my screensaver overloading the Mac OSX Catalina Screensaver Engine?

Tags: swift, macos, screensaver

I developed what I felt was a neat little program in processing. It sets up some rngs and then graphs the counts of each output of each rng. Here's the processing code. I don't think there are any problems on that end cause it runs fine in processing:

```
int [] randomCounts;
int [] gaussianCounts;
int [] monteCarloCounts;
int [] invMonteCarloCounts;
void setup(){
  size(1000,700);
  randomCounts = new int[500];
  gaussianCounts = new int[500];
  monteCarloCounts = new int[500];
  invMonteCarloCounts = new int[500];
}
float invMonteCarlo(){
  while (true){
    float r1 = random(1);
    float r2 = random(1);
    if (r2>r1){
      return r1;
    }
  }
}
float monteCarlo(){
  while (true){
    float r1 = random(1);
    float r2 = random(1);
    if (r2<r1){
      return r1;
    }
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  int randIndex = int(random(randomCounts.length));
  int gaussIndex = int(randomGaussian()*20+250);
  int monteIndex = int(monteCarlo()*monteCarloCounts.length);
  int invMonteIndex = int(invMonteCarlo()*invMonteCarloCounts.length);
  randomCounts[randIndex]++;
  gaussianCounts[gaussIndex]++;
  monteCarloCounts[monteIndex]++;
  invMonteCarloCounts[invMonteIndex]++;
  
  noStroke();
  int w = width/randomCounts.length;
  fill(0,255,0,150);
  for (int x = 0; x < gaussianCounts.length;x++){
    rect(x*w,height-gaussianCounts[x],w-1,gaussianCounts[x]);
  }
  fill(0,0,255,150);
  for (int x = 0;x < monteCarloCounts.length;x++){
    rect(x*w,height-monteCarloCounts[x],w-1,monteCarloCounts[x]);
  }
  fill(255,255,0,150);
  for (int x = 0;x < invMonteCarloCounts.length;x++){
    rect(x*w,height-invMonteCarloCounts[x],w-1,invMonteCarloCounts[x]);
  }
  fill(255,0,0,150);
  for (int x = 0; x < randomCounts.length; x++){
    rect(x*w,height-randomCounts[x],w-1,randomCounts[x]);
  }
}
void mousePressed(){
  for (int x = 0; x < randomCounts.length; x++){
    randomCounts[x] = 0;
    gaussianCounts[x] = 0;
    monteCarloCounts[x] = 0;
    invMonteCarloCounts[x] = 0;
  }
}
```

This code, again, works fine. I tried to do essentially the same stuff in swift, (which was kind of nuts) and XCode points out no errors. However, when I install the Saver in System Preferences, the preview is just black and stops functioning, for even other screensavers, and actually running the screensaver can't happen. It seems to get stuck somewhere, which prevents it from actually running in the engine.
Here is my swift code:

```
import Foundation
import ScreenSaver
import GameplayKit

class RandomGraphView: ScreenSaverView {
    private var randomCounts: [Int] = [500]
    private var gaussianCounts: [Int] = [500]
    private var shuffledCounts: [Int] = [500]
    private var monteCarloCounts: [Int] = [500]
    private var invMonteCarloCounts: [Int] = [500]
    
    private func MonteCarlo() -> Int{
        while true {
            let r1 = Int.random(in: 1...360)
            let r2 = Int.random(in: 1...360)
            if r2<r1 {
                return r1
            }
        }
    }

    private func invMonteCarlo() -> Int{
        while true {
            let r1 = Int.random(in: 1...360)
            let r2 = Int.random(in: 1...360)
            if r2>r1 {
                return r1
            }
        }
    }

    private func gaussian() -> Int{
        let gaussianD6 = GKGaussianDistribution(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 360)
        return gaussianD6.nextInt()
    }

    private func shuffled() -> Int{
        let shuffledD6 = GKShuffledDistribution(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 360)
        return shuffledD6.nextInt()
    }

    private func pullNumbers(){
        let randIndex = Int.random(in: 1...360)
        let gaussIndex = gaussian()
        let shuffIndex = shuffled()
        let monteCarloIndex = MonteCarlo()
        let invMonteCarloIndex = invMonteCarlo()
        randomCounts[randIndex]+=1
        gaussianCounts[gaussIndex]+=1
        shuffledCounts[shuffIndex]+=1
        monteCarloCounts[monteCarloIndex]+=1
        invMonteCarloCounts[invMonteCarloIndex]+=1
    }

    private func drawRandomBars(){
        for n in 1...360{
            let countBarRect = NSRect(x:(n-1)*4,y: 900, width:4, height: randomCounts[n])
            let countBar = NSBezierPath(rect: countBarRect)
            NSColor.red.setFill()
            countBar.fill()
        }
    }
    
    private func drawGaussianBars(){
        for n in 1...360{
            let countBarRect = NSRect(x: (n-1)*4, y: 900, width: 4, height: gaussianCounts[n])
            let countBar = NSBezierPath(rect: countBarRect)
            NSColor.green.setFill()
            countBar.fill()
        }
    }
    
    private func drawShuffledBars(){
        for n in 1...360{
            let countBarRect = NSRect(x: (n-1)*4, y: 900, width: 4, height: shuffledCounts[n])
            let countBar = NSBezierPath(rect: countBarRect)
            NSColor.systemBrown.setFill()
            countBar.fill()
        }
    }
    
    private func drawMonteCarloBars(){
        for n in 1...360{
            let countBarRect = NSRect(x: (n-1)*4, y: 900, width: 4, height: monteCarloCounts[n])
            let countBar = NSBezierPath(rect: countBarRect)
            NSColor.magenta.setFill()
            countBar.fill()
        }
    }
    
    private func drawInverseMonteCarloBars(){
        for n in 1...360{
            let countBarRect = NSRect(x: (n-1)*4, y: 900, width: 4, height: invMonteCarloCounts[n])
            let countBar = NSBezierPath(rect: countBarRect)
            NSColor.systemIndigo.setFill()
            countBar.fill()
        }
    }
    private func drawBackground(_ color:NSColor){
        let background = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        color.setFill()
        background.fill()
    }

    override init?(frame: NSRect, isPreview: Bool){
        super.init(frame: frame, isPreview: isPreview)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder){
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: NSRect){
        drawBackground(.white)
        pullNumbers()
        drawRandomBars()
        drawGaussianBars()
        drawShuffledBars()
        drawMonteCarloBars()
        drawInverseMonteCarloBars()
    }
    

    override func animateOneFrame(){
        super.animateOneFrame()
    }

}
```

Sorry for the long code, I genuinely have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I copied most of my scripting from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-make-a-custom-screensaver-for-mac-os-x-7e1650c13bd8) which works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set needsDisplay in animateOneFrame, like this:

```
override func animateOneFrame(){
    needsDisplay = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```swift
private var randomCounts: [Int] = [500]
```

is not equivalent to

```java
randomCounts = new int[500];
```

The former creates an array with a single number 500 inside, whereas the latter creates an array of 500 integers (I am not a Processing/Java expert but I assume they are initialized to 0). So your program would crash when `randIndex`, `gaussIndex`, etc. are larger than 0, because the index would be out of bounds.

Instead you probably wanted to use [init(repeating:count:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init): `private var randomCounts: [Int] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 500)`.

To avoid this kind of problem in general, you can improve your code by not writing `1...360` everywhere, but instead using `randomCounts.count` to refer to the length of the array. Similarly, instead of `for n in 1...360`, use something like `for (n, height) in monteCarloCounts.enumerated()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured out the issue with the arrays a little bit before I saw your answer, so the thing isn't crashing anymore, but it's still not rendering.

Comment: You should edit your question to include your updated code and more about what you've tried for debugging, otherwise it is hard to help with little information.